# Is there a way to disable group policy for a couple of minutes on a certain computer in a 2008 domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, group-policy

I'm trying to disable the group policy on a computer for a limited time without logging out and back in.
Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks for the replys.
It's actually necessary that the computer will continue receiving group policy updates.
My aim is to be able to clear the policy from the logged in session, do what I need to do (usually fix a problem) and then reapply the policy.

Comment: Sometime I'm required to fix a problem on a local computer and some times on a user's terminal session, and if i could find a tool that does exactly that and quickly, without having to reboot the computer or even log out of the session it would be fantastic as it will allow me to experience the problem with the user's environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have actually found a great solution, which does exactly what i wanted, on the fly, without the need to re-log or reboot the computer.
It seems like there's a free tool which gives you many more functions than just killing/reapplying the policy, but it also gives that.
The name of the tool is: Controlup by Smart-X , look for it in Google and thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This does not have a time-limit, but it would disable GPOs being set until you reverted it. I imagine it could be scripted if one was so inclined.

http://everydaynerd.com/how-to/disable-group-policy-service-on-windows-vista7

Comment: Yes, that would stop the Group Policy service. Updated/changed policies would not apply to the machine.  Previously applied policies would have already committed their settings to the machine. This will not "undo" any applied policy.